How to Implement AsyncRead and AsyncWrite for a Custom AsyncUtpStream in Rust?
I am trying to implement AsyncRead and AsyncWrite traits for a custom AsyncUtpStream that wraps a UDP-based uTP-like protocol implemented using tokio::net::UdpSocket. While my underlying UDP communication is working fine (e.g., sending and receiving packets as expected), I am facing issues in making my AsyncUtpStream compatible with Rust's async I/O traits.
Interaction Between Server and Client
I currently have the server and client interacting as expected over UDP using my custom AsyncUtpSocket. Here is a simple example of their communication:
Server Output:code
UDP server listening on 127.0.0.1:8080...
Received 20 bytes from 127.0.0.1:37776. Presumably a SYN packet.
---> Received SYN packet
Sent 20 bytes back to client.
Accepted connection from 127.0.0.1:37776
Received 5 bytes from 127.0.0.1:37776: "hello"
Received 18 bytes from 127.0.0.1:37776: "my name is shivank"

Client Output:code
UDP client sending packets...
Sent SYN packet to 127.0.0.1:8080
Received SYN-ACK packet
Connection established with the server
Sent 5 bytes to server: "hello"
Sent 18 bytes to server: "my name is shivank"

Relevant Code
Here is the relevant portion of my code:
AsyncUtpSocket
This struct handles UDP communication and provides methods like send_to and recv_from for sending/receiving packets asynchronously.Complete code
#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
pub struct AsyncUtpSocket {
    /// The underlying UDP socket (shared via Arc<Mutex<...>>).
    pub(crate) socket: Arc<Mutex<UdpSocket>>,
    /// The remote address (if "connected").
    pub(crate) connected_to: Option<SocketAddr>,
    /// Current congestion timeout (used for re-sends, etc.).
    pub(crate) congestion_timeout: u64,
    /// Current socket state (e.g., `New`, `SynSent`, etc.).
    pub(crate) state: SocketState,
}

pub async fn send_to(&self, buf: &[u8]) -> io::Result<usize> { /* ... */ }
pub async fn recv_from(&self, buf: &mut [u8]) -> io::Result<(usize, SocketAddr)> { /* ... */ }

AsyncUtpStream
This struct wraps AsyncUtpSocket and is intended to implement AsyncRead and AsyncWrite traits. Below is my current implementation:Complete code
pub struct AsyncUtpStream {
    /// The underlying async uTP-like socket
    pub socket: AsyncUtpSocket,

}
impl AsyncUtpStream {
    /// Bind to a local address (e.g., `"0.0.0.0:0"` for an ephemeral port).
    pub async fn bind<A>(addr: A) -> io::Result<AsyncUtpStream>
    where
        A: ToSocketAddrs + std::net::ToSocketAddrs,
    {
        debug!("Binding to socket");
        let socket = AsyncUtpSocket::bind(addr).await?;

        Ok(AsyncUtpStream { socket })
    }

    /// Connect to a remote address.
    pub async fn connect<A>(dst: A) -> io::Result<AsyncUtpStream>
    where
        A: ToSocketAddrs + std::net::ToSocketAddrs,
    {
        debug!("Creating stream and connecting to remote address");
        let socket = AsyncUtpSocket::connect(dst).await?;
        info!("Ending connection");
        Ok(AsyncUtpStream { socket })
    }
}

impl AsyncRead for AsyncUtpStream {
    fn poll_read(
        mut self: Pin<&mut Self>,
        cx: &mut Context<'_>,
        buf: &mut ReadBuf<'_>
    ) -> Poll<Result<()>> {
        /**
         I do not understand what to write here, as my recv_from is async and this is a sync function. 
         I have an idea that we have to pin this future and poll it, but I lack understanding of the approach.
        */
    }
}

impl AsyncWrite for AsyncUtpStream {
    fn poll_write(
        mut self: Pin<&mut Self>,
        cx: &mut Context<'_>,
        data: &[u8]
    ) -> Poll<Result<usize>> {
        /**
            Todo!()
        */
    }

    fn poll_flush(
        mut self: Pin<&mut Self>,
        cx: &mut Context<'_>
    ) -> Poll<Result<()>> {
        Poll::Ready(Ok(()))
    }

    fn poll_shutdown(
        mut self: Pin<&mut Self>,
        cx: &mut Context<'_>
    ) -> Poll<Result<()>> {
        Poll::Ready(Ok(()))
    }
}

The Problem

I am struggling with how to implement the poll_read method to handle asynchronous packet-based data (via recv_from) and properly populate the provided ReadBuf.

Similarly, I am unsure how to implement poll_write for sending data asynchronously over UDP.


What I Need Help With

How can I correctly implement poll_read to properly handle data from the underlying UDP socket and populate the ReadBuf?

Are there any patterns or best practices for implementing AsyncRead and AsyncWrite for a protocol built on top of UDP?

How should poll_write handle the asynchronous nature of UDP to ensure proper data delivery?


Additional Information

I am using tokio and tokio::net::UdpSocket for async networking.

The protocol is uTP-like, so it is packet-based rather than stream-based.

The AsyncUtpSocket already has methods for sending and receiving data (send_to and recv_from) that work as expected.


Any guidance or examples would be appreciated. Let me know if additional details or code snippets are required.

I attempted to implement the poll_read function for my custom AsyncUtpStream using Pin and Box::pin.

Please provide a definition for the struct AsyncUtpStream. We can't see what fields it has.

@cdhowie I have provided the definition of AsyncUtpStream

Too little context, but generally you need to create some sort of state of machine to describe current state of write/read to underlying socket and use that state machine in your Future implementation for AsyncUtpState. You cannot directly reuse the.send_to, recv_from methods, as they are transormed by compiler into opaque types implementing Future, and trying to invoke poll on those will result in a lot headache with lifetimes.

You cannot (easily) wrap these send_to and recv_from functions in AsyncWrite and AsyncRead.  We need to store a self-referential opaque future type, which is possible through the use of boxing and lifetime transmutation, provided that we enforce AsyncUtpStream is !Unpin (by adding a PhantomPinned member).
However, there are no fancy lifetime tricks we can use to get around the fact that send_to and recv_from borrow their buffers for the lifetime of the future.  This makes storing the future returned by these functions impossible if we just pass through the buffer, because poll_read and poll_write can only borrow the buffer provided to them for as long as poll_* is executing.
The only way I can see to make this work is to store a pair of intermediate buffers on AsyncUtpStream (one for reads and one for writes) and let send_to and recv_from use these instead.  This will result in a lot of buffer micro-managing where you need to be able to handle undersized and oversized reads/writes.  This is going to be complicated, on top of having to manually manage lifetimes with unsafe.
Here is an example of just a read implementation.  I believe this should be sound, but have not tested it.  A few things to note:

We add a PhantomPinned member to ensure that the struct is !Unpin.  This lets us soundly do self-referential stuff with a Pin<&mut Self> since we are guaranteed that the referent will never move.  In particular, we need to store a future that references the read buffer stored in a sibling field.  This is normally unsound, but pinning makes it sound.
We keep our own read buffer, which we have to manage. Once a read request completes, we have to dispense bytes from this buffer until it is empty, to ensure that we yield the bytes in the same order they were received.
We have to store the read future as a raw pointer that implicitly captures 'static.  This is because to access it, we need to transmute the captured lifetime to that of the AsyncUtcpStream.  Storing it as a raw pointer prevents accidentally using it with the wrong lifetime.  To obtain this pointer, we "simply" wrap the future in a Box<dyn Future> and call Box::into_raw.
We have to manually destroy the future, both when it completes and when AsyncUtpStream is dropped.  We can drop it by converting it back into a Box using Box::from_raw.  We have to make sure we convert it using the correct lifetime so dropping the inner future is sound.
When maintaining this code, you have to be careful to avoid breaking Rust's aliasing rules.  For example, while read_fut is Some, you cannot reference read_buffer at all. Doing so would cause immediate undefined behavior.

The many uses of unsafe here should scare you.  Assuming that this code is sound, it would be very easy to break during maintenance.  Note that I had to revise this answer multiple times to fix logic and soundness errors. This stuff is hard to get right.
If you can refactor recv_from and send_to to be more compatible with the poll_* signature, that would make this substantially easier.
pub struct AsyncUtpStream {
    socket: AsyncUtpSocket,

    read_fut: Option<*mut dyn Future<Output = io::Result<(usize, SocketAddr)>>>,

    read_buffer: Vec<u8>,
    read_buffer_start: usize,

    _pin: PhantomPinned,
}

impl AsyncUtpStream {
    pub fn new(socket: AsyncUtpSocket) -> Self {
        Self {
            socket,
            read_fut: None,
            read_buffer: vec![],
            read_buffer_start: 0,
            _pin: PhantomPinned,
        }
    }

    fn get_or_create_read_fut<'a>(
        self: Pin<&'a mut Self>,
        buffer_size: usize,
    ) -> Pin<&'a mut (dyn Future<Output = io::Result<(usize, SocketAddr)>> + 'a)> {
        let this = unsafe { self.get_unchecked_mut() };

        let p = this.read_fut.get_or_insert_with(|| {
            this.read_buffer.resize(buffer_size, 0);

            let b: Box<dyn Future<Output = io::Result<(usize, SocketAddr)>>> =
                Box::new(this.socket.recv_from(&mut this.read_buffer[..]));

            // The cast here transmutes the lifetime 'a to 'static.
            Box::into_raw(b) as *mut _
        });

        unsafe { Pin::new_unchecked(&mut **p) }
    }

    fn destroy_read_fut<'a>(self: Pin<&'a mut Self>) {
        unsafe {
            if let Some(p) = self.get_unchecked_mut().read_fut.take() {
                let _: Box<dyn Future<Output = io::Result<(usize, SocketAddr)>> + 'a> =
                    Box::from_raw(p);
            }
        }
    }
}

impl Drop for AsyncUtpStream {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        unsafe {
            Pin::new_unchecked(self).destroy_read_fut();
        }
    }
}

impl AsyncRead for AsyncUtpStream {
    fn poll_read(
        mut self: Pin<&mut Self>,
        cx: &mut Context<'_>,
        buf: &mut ReadBuf<'_>,
    ) -> Poll<io::Result<()>> {

        // Check if we have any already-read data available.  If not, we'll read
        // from a recv_from future.
        //
        // We have to check if self.read_fut is Some first; if it is,
        // self.read_buffer is currently exclusively borrowed by the current
        // read future, and using it even to read the current length would be
        // undefined behavior!
        if self.read_fut.is_some() || self.read_buffer.len() <= self.read_buffer_start {
            let fut = self.as_mut().get_or_create_read_fut(buf.remaining());

            let result = match fut.poll(cx) {
                Poll::Pending => return Poll::Pending,
                Poll::Ready(r) => r,
            };

            self.as_mut().destroy_read_fut();

            let (read, _) = match result {
                Err(e) => return Poll::Ready(Err(e)),
                Ok(v) => v,
            };

            if read == 0 {
                // We can fast-succeed in this case.
                return Poll::Ready(Ok(()));
            }

            unsafe {
                self.as_mut().get_unchecked_mut().read_buffer_start = 0;
                self.as_mut().get_unchecked_mut().read_buffer.truncate(read);
            };
        }

        let to_read = (self.read_buffer.len() - self.read_buffer_start).min(buf.remaining());

        buf.initialize_unfilled_to(to_read).copy_from_slice(
            &self.read_buffer[self.read_buffer_start..(self.read_buffer_start + to_read)],
        );

        unsafe {
            self.get_unchecked_mut().read_buffer_start += to_read;
        }

        Poll::Ready(Ok(()))
    }
}

